# How to fill a UiRenderer with a safeHtml value?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have the following UiRenderer (template renerer file: not widget binder), and my issue is with the field `desc`

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder">
    <ui:with field='logo' type='java.lang.String' />
    <ui:with field='name' type='java.lang.String' />
    <ui:with field='desc' type='java.lang.String' />
    <ui:with field='prodCnt' type='java.lang.String' />
    <div class="shopMainCell">
        <div class="shopLogo">
            <img src='{logo}' />
        </div>
        <div class="shopProps">
        <div class="name">
            <ui:text from='{name}'></ui:text> 
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            <ui:text from='{desc}'></ui:text> 
        </div>
        <div class="prodCnt">
            <ui:text from='{prodCnt}'></ui:text> 
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

In fact `desc` containes HTML and when I pass the value to the `UiRenderer` all my html tags become uninterpreted by the browser, since they are escaped.

Trying to use  with `SafeHtml` is not accepted (as an argument to ui:text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `<ui:safehtml from='{...}'/>` in your `uiRenderer` template.

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder">
    <ui:with field='logo' type='java.lang.String' />
    <ui:with field='name' type='java.lang.String' />
    <ui:with field='desc' type='com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml' />
    <ui:with field='prodCnt' type='java.lang.String' />
    <div class="shopMainCell">
        <div class="shopLogo">
            <img src='{logo}' />
        </div>
        <div class="shopProps">
        <div class="name">
            <ui:text from='{name}'/>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            <ui:safehtml from='{desc}'/>
        </div>
        <div class="prodCnt">
            <ui:text from='{prodCnt}'/>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: thanks, I received also an answer on the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/3yRVRkQDOa8